# What's a Python "system library"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In a [google cloud article](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/) for the App Engine Standard Environment, it states:

> System libraries not available in the App Engine standard Python environment

I'm wondering ... A. What are "system libraries" in this context? ... B. Is this standard terminology, or is the definition specific to this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a summary description (suitable for the condensed format of the comparison table) of the standard environment sandbox restrictions described in a bit more details in [The Sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_The_sandbox). Most of them fall in the OS/system control area, probably the reason for the ***system*** name. Technically the restrictions may be spread in several standard python libraries, I remember I hit some in the `os` one, for example.

Note: these restrictions are applicable only to the 1st generation standard environment (python 2), the 2nd generation (python 3) sandbox is [more relaxed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#restrictions) from this perspective.